# What is filter paper?

Tags: filtering

A recipe that I'm trying to make says: "Place mixture into a loaf pan that has been sprayed with pan release and lined with filter paper."

I'm pretty sure that "pan release" is the generic version of PAM, but I don't know what filter paper is. Is it another word for wax paper?

A quick search turned up a bunch of coffee filters and lab equipment.

Comment: I dunno, I think wax paper would be phenomenally bad at filtering anything. Same with parchment paper, the other candidate I can think of for lining a pan. The only filter paper in my kitchen is the package of coffee filters, which are round and fluted and really bad at lining a loaf pan. So I have no idea what your recipe could be referring to.

Comment: You definitely don't want to put wax paper in the oven, unless you want burnt paper and melted wax on your food.  Parchment paper is the oven-safe equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would assume it's a synonym for parchment paper.  And yes, pan release is a generic term for any food release spray.

Answer (score 2):

A Wikipedia article shows the following types of filter paper: Air filters, Coffee filter, Fuel filters, Laboratory filters, Oil filters, Tea bags

I did not find anything helpful on Amazon.

I don't think parchment paper would qualify as filter paper but after I searched "Place mixture into a loaf pan that has been sprayed with pan release and lined with filter paper" and read the recipe (which I found in lots of places) it looks to me like they are referring to parchment paper and it looks like they possibly, along the way or originally used the wrong term.